# Stacked Bar Graph with Errorbars in Pandas / Matplotlib

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I want to show my Data in two (or more) stacked Bargraphs inkluding Errorbars. My Code leans on an working Example, but uses df`s at input instead of Arrays.

I tried to set the df-output to an array, but this will not work

```py
from uncertain_panda import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


raw_data = {'': ['Error', 'Value'],'Stars': [3, 18],'Cats': [2,15],'Planets': [1,12],'Dogs': [2,16]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)
df.set_index('', inplace=True)
print(df)

N = 2
ind = np.arange(N)     
width = 0.35        

first_Value   = df.loc[['Value'],['Cats','Dogs']]
second_Value  = df.loc[['Value'],['Stars','Planets']]

first_Error  = df.loc[['Error'],['Cats','Dogs']]
second_Error = df.loc[['Error'],['Stars','Planets']]

p1 = plt.bar(ind, first_Value,  width, yerr=first_Error)
p2 = plt.bar(ind, second_Value, width, yerr=second_Error, bottom=first_Value)

plt.xticks(ind, ('Pets', 'Universe'))
plt.legend((p1[0], p2[0]), ('Cats', 'Dogs', 'Stars', 'Planets'))

plt.show()
```

I expect an output like this:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_stacked.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-stacked-py

Instead i get this error:
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: Not all matplotlib arguments take dataframes as input. If `df` is a dataframe, `df.values` will be the respective numpy array.

Comment: no, there is the same erroe massage. with adding .values i get this output: [[1.2 2.5]], with adding .valie.tolist() i get this output: [[1.2, 2.5]] but i think i need this: (1.2, 2.5)

Comment: My first comment wasn't a question; that is a fact. You need to see for yourself how that helps in applying it to the working Example you found.